# Calculating the variance of softmax

Tags: neural-networks, classification, cross-entropy, softmax

I'm working through Dive Into Deep Learning right now and am struggling with the following question:

1. We can explore the connection between exponential families and the
   softmax in some more depth.

   1. Compute the second derivative of the cross-entropy loss for the softmax.
   2. Compute the variance of the distribution given by $softmax(\bf{o})$ and show that it matches the second
      derivative computed above.

For part 1, I've already calculated the 2nd derivative as $softmax(\bf{o})_j(1-softmax(\bf{o})_j)$, where $\bf{o}$ is a vector given by $\bf{Wx+b}$, where $\bf{x}$ is a vector of inputs, and $\bf{W,b}$ are weights and biases.

For part 2, I am unsure where to begin. I know $Var[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$, and $E[X] = \Sigma xf(x)$ or $\int xf(x)dx$, where $f(x)$ is the pdf. But in this case, I'm not really sure what $x$ would be other than the output of the softmax function, and I'm not sure how to determine the pdf of that.

Comment: Welcome to the site! "Compute the variance of the distribution given by and" seems to be missing a word or symbol.

Comment: Hi John, yes thank you. The LaTeX didn't copy over. I have updated the original post

Answer (score 0):

I think the distribution given by softmax(o) is a Bernoulli distribution with probabilities $p = softmax(o)$, so the variance is:
$$Var[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = \text{softmax}(o)(1 - \text{softmax}(o))$$
details are [here](https://pandalab.me/archives/softmax_regression)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).